# Angular logging in via http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Being new to Angular, I am trying to build a login method for my mobile application using Ionic.

Here is my login view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign-In" name="login-view">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
          </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login(data)">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and here is my javascript within services.js to login using $http -

```
angular.module('APP').service('AuthService', function ($q, $http, URLS) {
    var login = function (name, pw) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            name = 'demoperson';
            pw = 'Abc';

            var dataObj = {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: name,
                password: pw
            };
            var res = $http.post(URLS.LOGINURL, dataObj)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.message = data;
                resolve('Login success.');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));

                reject('Login Failed.');
            });
        });
    };
});
```

The issue is every time the request doesn't hit the server and I end up in the error callback without any error. I am not able to see what error occurred and Fiddler doesn't capture the error.

Is there something obvious missing?

Comment: check your error response it is not related with javascript...

Comment: No errors in the console? Can you see any network request at all?

Comment: I don't get an error response and I see nothing in the console. I don't see the network request through Fiddler or on the web server. @tymeJV

Comment: numerous issues. `var login` isn't being set as property of service and there is no `$scope` in a service. Where's the controller that uses the service?

Comment: The login function is getting called from the view @charlietfl

Comment: view can't see a service. Can pass function as reference to controller but `ng-click` will only call what can be seen in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully your `AuthService` will be more than just a login method. Try taking this approach:

```
angular.module('APP')
   .factory('AuthService', function ($q, $http, URLS) {
       var Auth = {
          login: function (name, pw) {
             var dfd = $q.defer();
             var dataObj = {
                 grant_type: 'password',
                 username: name,
                 password: pw
             };
             $http.post(URLS.LOGINURL, dataObj)
                  .then(function (res) {
                      var handled = 'handle response here';
                      dfd.resolve(handled);
                  }, function (err) {
                      dfd.reject({error: err});
                  });
             return dfd.promise;
          },
          logout: logoutMethod
       };
       return Auth;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $q. $http already has built-in promises.

```
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "/something",
        data: {...}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
    });
```

Also, does your controller have a method on `$scope` called `login`? It is not obvious from your example that `ng-click="login(data)"` will call your  `var login = function (name, pw)` function. Also the login call passes 1 parameter and your service login takes two. Whats going on there?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a factory service:

```
angular.module('APP').factory('AuthService', function ($q, $http, URLS) {
    var login = function (name, pw) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            name = 'demoperson';
            pw = 'Abc';

            var dataObj = {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: name,
                password: pw
            };
            var res = $http.post(URLS.LOGINURL, dataObj)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //$scope.message = data;
                //this should be done from the returned promise.
                resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));

                reject('Login Failed.');
            });
        });
    };
    return login;
});
```

And of course, you'd need to attach the dependency to the `$scope` so you could do just `login()` from the form. Or have a controller method do that instead.

Also, you probably want:

```
var login = function (obj) {
   obj.username = obj.username || 'demoperson';
   obj.password = obj.password || 'Abc';

   var dataObj = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: obj.username,
            password: obj.password
        };
```

Given that you pass the function an object on your form.

Example of controller:

```
angular.module('APP').controller('myController', ['$scope', 'AuthService', function($scope, login){
    $scope.login = function(data){
        login(data).then(function(message){
            $scope.message = message;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: there is no `$scope` in service

Comment: Well, I meant from a controller.

Comment: look at the success handler, `$scope` in it